# Scraping Amcharts interactive data

Tags: json, web-scraping, amcharts

I'm trying to get the stock market cap data from the chart on this page: https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/market-cap

I first looked in the network responses and didn't see anything.  I can see that divs with class `amcharts-balloon-div` appear when hovering over the chart (and the date and value appear on the chart), but I can't track down where in the JS this is getting called (it might just be that I don't know where to look).  I also noticed that a `chartData` property will sometimes show up in the window object, however, it's not always there.

I'm hoping someone can recommend how to find and get the data and what the process should be for tracking it down, starting from the point of loading the page.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is hiding inside a variable inside a script on that page. Extracting it is a somewhat convoluted process (and there may be others I haven't thought of), but this should get you there (using a couple of python libraries):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/market-cap',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

params = (
    ('t', 'AAPL'),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/assets/php/market_cap.php', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = bs(response.text,'lxml')
#the above gets you the page contents, with the target data; we now look for the scripts on that page
scpt = soup.select('script')
val_dict = {} #intialize a dictionary to house the data at the end
#there are numerous scripts on that page; we need to single out the relevant script
for s in scpt:
    if len(s.contents)>0 and 'var chartData = ' in s.contents[0]:
        #the above selects the one script with the data; from now on, everything is string and list manipulations to extract the data and append it to the dictionary
        vr = s.contents[0].split('var chartData = ')[1].split(';\r')[0]
        vals = vr.split(',')
        for d,v in zip(vals[::2],vals[1::2]):
            val_dict[d.split(':')[1]]= v.split(':')[1].replace('}','')
```

Random portion of the output:

```
date:  "2005-06-10" value:  29.19
date:  "2005-06-13" value:  29.26
date:  "2005-06-14" value:  29.34
date:  "2005-06-15" value:  30.27
date:  "2005-06-16" value:  30.96
```

etc.

Comment: Brilliant stuff.  Can I ask how you managed to track that down?  Is there a general process you'd recommend beyond the things I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah I don't know of any general purpose process, I'm afraid (I wish one existed). What I normally do is look for json strings in xhr; if (like here) there's none, i just sort the responses by size - usually (but, of course, not always) the data lurks in the larger sized responses (as was the case here). From there on, it's just heavy lifting...

Comment: One thing I did notice after you identified the link - it's in the iframe as the `src` attribute (not sure how I missed that before).  Searching the network responses for the relative link `assets/php/market_cap.php` shows the relevant files and it's easier from there.  The iframe page in this case is very simple and it's just about parsing the script like in your answer.  I did also see that the `chartData` attribute is always added to `window` when loading the iframe page in isolation, so there are probably other tools to get it directly from `window` if someone prefers that method.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah One such other tool would be using Selenium, I guess.